# Getting substrings using 3 spaces as first occurrence of specified string to return index

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string where words are either seperated by one or three spaces.
I am tryng to print the set of words that are seperated by every 3 spaces.
I get as far as the the first set of words that reach 3 spaces and enter an infinite loop:

```
String sentence = "one one one   three   three one   three one";
    int lenght=0;
    int start=0;
    int threeSpaces = sentence.indexOf("   ");//get index where 1st 3 spaces occur

    while (lenght<sentence.length()) {



    String word = sentence.substring(start, threeSpaces);//get set of words separated by 3 spaces
    System.out.println(word);
    start=threeSpaces;//move starting pos
    length=threeSpaces;//increase length 
    threeSpaces= sentence.indexOf("   ", start);//find the next set of 3 spaces from the last at index threeSpaces

    }//end while
    }
```

}

Output: one one one

at this point start = 11, length=11, and threeSpaces=11!
 threespaces is the problem, i was expecting the value to be index of the next set of 3 spaces '   ' from the new start index (11)...any input appreciated...

PS title is a bit all over the place could notthink of an easier one...

Comment: What about using `String[] wordsWith3SpacesBetween = sentence.split("3literalspaces");`  (use 3 space chars for 3literalspaces - spaces don't post well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the start index as `start + 1`, else you will get the index of the same 3 whitespaces in the `sentence`:

```
threeSpaces = sentence.indexOf("   ", start + 1);
```

But you have to do some more task. You need to check the index of `"   "` before actually invoking `substring`, because when there is no more `"   "`, the index will be `-1`, and you will get `StringIndexOutOfBounds` exception. For that you would change the `while` loop condition to:

```
while (lenght<sentence.length() && threeSpaces != -1)
```

this will stop the `while` loop, as soon as the index of 3 spaces comes out to be `-1`, that would mean, there are no more 3 whitespaces.

---

A better way to solve this problem is to `split` on 3 whitespaces:

```
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s{3}");

for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be more simply done with the following code:

```
String[] myWords = sentence.split("   ");
for (String word : myWords) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `I have a string where words are either seperated by one or three
>   spaces. I am tryng to print the set of words that are seperated by every 3 spaces.`

You should use `String#split` with 3 spaces:

```
String[] tokens = sentence.split(" {3}");
```

Comment: *I am tryng to print the set of words that are seperated by every 3 spaces.* - You missed the second sentence in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, split looks like the go:
    String phrase= "one one   three   one one one   three three   one one one    three three three   one one one";
    String[] split2 = phrase.split("   ");
    for( String three:split2)
      System.out.println(three);

Output:
one one
three
one one one
three three
one one one
 three three three
one one one